# Bootstrap: data-slide-to index with multiple carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created multiple carousels on one page. These carousels have unique ids and thumbnail links which all have the `data-slide-to` attribute.

The problem is, that Bootstrap create an item index over ALL carousels. For example the first carousels has data-slide-to from index 0 to 7, the second carousel the data-slide-to starts with 8.

How to renew the index for every carousel.

I tried to initialize every carousel with specific JS call, and via the data- attribute, same issue.

```
<div id="carouselIdx_6" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active"><a href="/assets/…"><img src="/assets/…"></a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="/assets/…"><img src="/…"></a></div>
    </div>
    <ol class="indicator-small carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselIdx_6" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="" src="/assets/…"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIdx_6" data-slide-to="1"><img class="" src="/assets/…"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

```
<div id="carouselIdx_7" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active"><a href="/assets/…"><img src="/assets/…"></a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="/assets/…"><img src="/…"></a></div>
    </div>
    <ol class="indicator-small carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselIdx_7" data-slide-to="2" class="active"><img class="" src="/assets/…"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIdx_7" data-slide-to="3"><img class="" src="/assets/…"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It seams that jQuery is responsible for indexing the data-slide-to attribute. How to avoid or reinitialize on every carousel?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/9i12DqIM8W - Not sure what you're doing elsewhere with the initialization, but if you follow the Bootstrap documentation, each carousel operates individually.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected. I followed up the docs line by line, but always I got a wrong index. I don't have the `data-slide-to` in my code, it will be added after initialization. The initialization will be through the `data-ride` and `carousel` class. In the footer I only have jQuery and Bootstrap JS will be loaded. I tried also the JS initialization with and not the data type - same issue.